# How to rewrite Keras Stateful LSTM in pure Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, lstm-stateful

Anyone could share an idea/blog/code snipet on how to convert a Keras Stateful LSTM into pure Tensorflow model? And then train it on batch..

Tensorflow doesn't support Keras **Stateful** LSTM on TPUs. Their devs refused to fix it.

I have tons of TPU time reserved and no way to use it for now. Any help is appreciated.

Model example and code to train:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(window_size, n_steps, inputs_n), stateful=True)) 
model.add(Dense(outputs_n, activation='sigmoid'))
…
H = model.train_on_batch(X, y)
```

GitHub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28837

Comment: Can you share the link to github issue that you raised for this? What is your TF version?

Comment: version doesn't matter. this doesn't work in any TF version.

Comment: Stateful models work on TPUs but they are atrocious for performance. Batches has to be processed in order making it impossible to parallelize the calculations.